# QGIS expression using Aggregate and start_point to select a vector within a buffer

Tags: qgis, expression

I am trying to put a default value of a field so that the value always updates once any change is make item. Either the expression builder or function editor are fine.  I'm more familiar with the expression builder so I went that path. There should only ever be 1 pole within 5m of the start point so I can use concatenate but if there is a way to find the closest pole that would be best.

If I use the code below I get no info no matter how large I make the distance.

```
 aggregate( layer:='Poles', aggregate:=' concatenate' , expression:="Pole Id", filter:=buffer(start_point( geometry(@parent)) ,0.00005),',')
```

With this code I get every item no matter how small I make the distance.

```
aggregate( layer:='Poles', aggregate:=' concatenate' , expression:="Pole Id", filter:=geom_to_wkt(buffer(start_point( geometry(@parent)) ,0.00005)),',')
```

I tried to find an answer but this was the closest I could find.  I don't have enough rep to add a comment so I had to post a new question. [@csk](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/81764/csk)  [Close but not quite answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326523/qgis-select-by-expression-buffer-selection)

Comment: FYI, when you "at" someone in a question, they don't get a message or any kind of notification. `@username` only works in the comment section, when that user has previously commented on that same post. (SE is kindof an anti-social media website in that way.)

Comment: For the `filter` input, you need a function that gives true/false as its output, but the output of the `buffer` function is a geometry. Try something along the lines of: `intersects($geometry,buffer(start_point( geometry(@parent)) ,0.00005))`

Comment: I know the "at" function didn't work cause I had to manually do the link.  There is also no way to message you either but I though it would get your attention that way.   aggregate( 'lakeland_power_poles_2ea67cd7_23c8_42f9_92e8_564dc5d422cc', 'concatenate',"Pole Id",intersects($geometry,buffer(start_point( geometry(@parent)) ,0.00005))) seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working thanks to @csk suggestion was

```
 aggregate( 'Poles', 'concatenate',"Pole Id",intersects($geometry,buffer(start_point( geometry(@parent)) ,0.00005)))
```

The nearest option would still be best but I can't seem to get that working with start_point.

Answer (score 4):

When the Aggregate functions are getting you down, try RefFunctions.

1. Install the RefFunctions plugin. This adds a variety of useful custom functions to the expression builder, including `geomnearest`.

   > **geomnearest function**
   >
   > Retrieve target field value from the nearest target feature in target layer. Syntax: `geomnearest(targetLayer,targetField)`
   >
   > Arguments
   >
   > `targetLayer` → the name of a currently loaded layer, for example 'myLayer'.
   >
   > `targetField` → a field in target layer we want as result when source feature is within target feature, for example 'myField'. 
   >   If targetField is equal to '$geometry' The WKT geometry of targetFeature willbe retrieved. If otherwise is equal to '$distance' the calculated distance between source and target features will be returned
2. For the default field value, use `geomnearest` to auto-fill the field with the targetField of the nearest point, *no matter how far away that point is*. (note: I tested this expression, and it worked)

   ```
   geomnearest('Poles','Pole Id')
   ```

---

I tried to find a solution using `geomdistance` to auto-fill the field with the targetField of the nearest point, *as long as that point is within a specified distance*. However, I couldn't quite make it work. I'm including my best attempt; feel free to use it as a starting point. Comment if you find a solution, or feel free to post as a separate answer.

```
  if( distance( start_point($geometry), geomnearest('Poles',$geometry))<5, geomnearest('Poles','Pole Id'), NULL)
```

The error seems to come from using `geomnearest` to get a feature's geometry. I can get other RefFunctions to work with `$geometry` as a parameter, but not `geomnearest`. When I use the recommended syntax from the function description, `geomnearest('Poles','$geometry')`, I get this error:

> Eval Error: 'QgsGeometry' object has no attribute 'exportToWkt'

But if I use the syntax that seems right to me, `geomnearest('Poles',$geometry)`, I get this error:

> Eval Error: error: targetFieldName not present.

You can probably get around this by adding the WKT geometry as a text field, using the field calculator and `geom_to_WKT($geometry)`. Then substitute for the second parameter in the distance function above: `geom_from_WKT(geomnearest('Poles','mygeometryfield'))`

Comment: This definitely helps get me on the right path.  Only issue is I can't pick start point and it seems just to take the nearest two features from all the poles and lines and only uses that point with geomnearest('Poles','Pole Id').  Is there a way you can specify geomneareast to use start_point?