# Selecting points near lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, line, proximity, select-by-location

In QGIS 3.22.16 I try to select and delete some roads (lines) that have a False value in the attribute table. Along with that, I need to delete all the gullies (points)along these road.

I don't have any related Field in both layer. The majority of them are not overlapping on those roads. I think of creating some buffers around those roads. And using the select by location tool to highlight those points.

Is there a better way to select those points that are along the False roads?

Comment: I guess that's the most straightforward way.

Comment: Join attribute by nearest: if two layers are not overlapping, I'd use that tool to join a field (False values) from lines to points.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the `select-by-expression` tool in qgis.
With selected POINT_Layer use the fowlling expression (substitute *100* by the wanted buffer width):

```
within($geometry, buffer(aggregate('ROAD_LAYER','collect',$geometry),100))
```

[image]

This is based on: [qgis-select-by-expression-buffer-selection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326523/qgis-select-by-expression-buffer-selection)

> Use the collect function to create a
> multiline geometry. Use this multiline geometry in the intersects
> function. Because we're using collect on a different layer, we have to
> put it inside the aggregate() function

Answer (score 0):

You may use the ovelay_nearest fonction to select the point (do it before deleting the line) this way :

```
 overlay_nearest( 
     layer:='LINE' -- set here the name of your road layer
    ,filter:=  "LINE_FIELD" = 'False' --filter the target features to check, set it to get roads that have a False value in the attribute table
    ,limit:=-1 --limit the number of matching features. If not set, only the nearest feature will be returned. If set to -1, returns all the matching features
    ,max_distance:=120 --an optional distance to limit the search of matching features, set it to an appropriate value to only get point close to your line
    )
```

This will let you select only the point that are less than 120 unit (adjust the value to your need) from the LINE layer where the "LINE_FIELD" is equal to 'False' (adapt this to your actual layer and field name)

[image]